# Creating one-to-many relationship in Access shows only " Indeterminate" Relationship Type option

Tags: database, ms-access, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, erd

So basically I am trying to design my simple Employee/Mission Tracking Database using Access.

I wanted to create a relationship between `Employee` table and `Mission` table ( many-to-many). Therefore, I needed to create a bridge-or conjunction- entity, I named it `Mission_Assignment`. Obviously, PKs of the two related tables ( **Mission_ID** and **Employee_ID**) should be included in this bridge entity as foreign keys.

When I tried to join `Mission_Assignment` with `Mission` by dragging the PK **Mission_ID** to the other table, Access didn't show me the option of making this relation as one-to-many, even if I have checked the Enforce refrential integrity box. The only option I got is "Indeterminate" relationship type!

I want to know why this happened? Why can't I have this one-to-many relationship? 
I tried to change the data type of the PK of the related table using Lookup Wizard, in order to be recognized as a foreign key in the conjunction table, but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the structure of your [Mission] table. I suspect that [Mission_ID] (or whatever column from [Mission] you are trying to use in the Relationship) is not actually designated as the Primary Key for that table.

Access determines the Relationship Type as follows:

```
[Table1].[Field]    [Table2].[Field]    Relationship Type
------------------  ------------------  -----------------
PK or Unique        PK or Unique        One-to-One
PK or Unique        Not (PK or Unique)  One-to-Many
Not (PK or Unique)  Not (PK or Unique)  Indeterminate
```

Comment: That's right! What I did is tha made the two PKs of the related table as ONE composite PK for the MISSION_ASSIGNMENT table. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue however after reading the above i checked closely and one of the primary key was "indexed: Yes (Duplicate OK)"..
I changed this to no duplicates and it allowed the relationship to be established.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have some advice about your answer. As it is currently written, this is more like a comment on the original answer than a unique answer. You should [edit] it to be a stand-alone answer; it's fine to refer to Gord's answer, but do so in a reliable way ("above" and "below" aren't reliable, as the order can be random). The details about exactly what you found caused the issue for you may be valuable for other users - make sure that difference stands out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue attempting to create a relationship between two tables (**ReportInfo and Inspection Team**)
I decided to make ReportNo of datatype Short text, the PK because it was the main link between all other tables. In my ReportInfo Table, I also had an ID that would auto increment and this was initially the PK but it didn't make sense since the other tables required ReportNo as the FK. 
The **Indeterminate** option was the only one available when attempting to link with the two tables I mentioned earlier.

As I changed the PK, it solved the issue.